# Invoking scons from a Python script

Tags: python, scons

I'm new to scons and Python.
I was wondering if there's a way to invoke scons from within a python script.

My python script accepts from the user, a list of directories where the code to be compiled together is located (in addition to doing some other non-trivial things).
It also generates a string which is to be used as a name of the executable created
by scons.

I want to pass this information from my python script to scons, and then invoke scons.
Is there a simple way to do this?

I can think of the following possibilities:

- use `subprocess.call("scons"...)` I'm not sure if scons accepts all the info I need to pass as command line arguments
- have the python script write into a file. Have the SConscript parse the file and get the information passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive done this using the `subprocess.call()` python function to encapsulate the somewhat long and complex command line args needed for the particular project I was working on. There are those that argued that the invocation should have been simpler so as not to need to encapsulate it, but that's a different subject :)

One option to consider instead of using command line arguments is to use the `SCONSFLAGS` environment variable as mentioned [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#AEN2132). Personally, I prefer not to use this option.

All the options you need can be passed in as command line options. A good way to customize and handle SCons command line args is with the SCons [AddOption()](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#AEN2411) function.  Additionally, you can get simple `variable=value` variables by using the SCons [ARGUMENTS dictionary](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x2445.html). Other related SCons command line functions are [GetOption()](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#AEN2158) and [SetOption()](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#AEN2183).

Regarding passing in a string for the executable name: SCons may not like this. At the very least, consider you execute your script once with a particular executable string, then a second time with a different one, then you want to clean, you may end up leaving executables around if SCons isnt executed with the same executable name.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess it's possible in theory. The `scons` executable itself is just a python script and all it does is execute `SCons.Script.main()` after modifying the `sys.path` variable. But you would probably have to start digging deep into the source to really understand how to make it do things you want.

A much cleaner solution is calling your script from the SConscript file, which is probably the intended usage and should prove much easier.

Comment: I looked into directly calling `SCons.Script.main()` once, and decided it wasnt worth it. I went for wrapping the call in a `subprocess.call()` invocation and handling the command line args as mentioned in my answer. I think trying to bypass the actual scons script could lead to a world of hurt :)

Comment: I guess this doesn't answer my question: If I call my Python script from the SConscript, how do I pass information to it that I have just obtained _before_ invoking scons?

Comment: Is there a real need to invoke your script before scons? You can import your script as a module from the SConscript file and then execute as necessary, gathering necessary input from the user. While technically not the same, there's no difference as far as the user is concerned. If that's not an option, then the route proposed by Brandy is a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. I ended up using this method:

The python script writes a list of options into a text file, closes it, and invokes `scons -f MySConscript_file` using a subprocess call. The SConstruct reads values from the text file into a list, and uses them.